# Automatic createdAt and updatedAt fields in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

In my collection I'd like to have automatically generated `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields that would contain the date of when the object was inserted / updated for the last time - kind of like it's happening in Ruby on Rails. Currently I'm doing this with an observer similar to this one:

```
MyCollection.find({}).observeChanges({
  changed: function(id, changes) {
    MyCollection.update(id, ...);
  },
});
```

Is there a better / more efficient / more straightforward way?

Comment: To catch client updates and inserts you can use deny() as recommended in the [Unofficial FAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-can-i-alter-every-document-before-it-is-added-to-the-database).

Comment: I don't think the following meteorite package uses `observeChanges` to accomplish similar functionality, so I guess their way is better than yours: https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks

```
collection.before.insert (userId, doc) ->
  doc.createdAt = new Date().valueOf #toISOString()
```

Answer (score 6):

I use Collection2. It supports `autoValue` in the schema, a function that computes the forced value of a field. As these two fields are used in all collections, you can save them to a variable:

```coffeescript
@SchemaHelpers =
  createdAt:
    type: Date
    autoValue: ->
      if @isInsert
        return new Date
      if @isUpsert
        return $setOnInsert: new Date
      if @isUpdate
        @unset()
        return
  updatedAt:
    type: Date
    autoValue: ->
      return new Date
```

And then in the collection:

```
Schema = {}
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts")
Schema.Posts = new SimpleSchema
  createdAt: SchemaHelpers.createdAt
  updatedAt: SchemaHelpers.updatedAt
  title:
    type: String
    max: 30
  body:
    type: String
    max: 3000
Posts.attachSchema(Schema.Posts)
```

This solution makes `updatedAt` always present and its value will be very close to `createdAt` when it is just inserted (not necessarily the same). If you need `updatedAt` not to be set when inserting, you can use something like the example in the [Collection2 readme](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/collection2):

```javascript
updatedAt: {
  type: Date,
  autoValue: function() {
    if (this.isUpdate) {
      return new Date();
    }
  },
  denyInsert: true,
  optional: true
},
```

but this does not handle [upserts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update). I don't know any good solution that handles upserts correctly and leaves the field empty at inserts.